# Convert MP4 to Ogg with C#

Tags: c#, ogg

Does anyone know a simple way of converting a mp4 file to an ogg file?

Have to do it, but don't have much knowlegde about it, and all I can find are programs, not examples or libraries.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend dispatching this to FFMPEG - http://www.ffmpeg.org/ - using a [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) and command line arguments.  You can redirect I/O if you need to (e.g. logging).  Just do something like [process.WaitForExit()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8.aspx) after you've started it.  You could do this on a background thread ([BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx), [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbf0f1ct.aspx), etc...) if you need to not block the UI.

Answer (score 4):

Extending Chad's answer I used the [NReco.VideoConverter which is a helpful wrapper for FFMPEG](http://www.nrecosite.com/video_converter_net.aspx). My code to convert a MP4 to OGG is as follows.

1.Save the file to a temporary file in local storage.

```
var path = Path.GetTempPath() + name;
using (var file = File.Create(path))
{
 stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
 await stream.CopyToAsync(file);
 file.Close();
 return path;
}
```

2.Now use the video converter to convert the file, simple!

```
var output = new MemoryStream();
var ffMpeg = new FFMpegConverter();
ffMpeg.ConvertMedia(filePath, output, Format.ogg);
output.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
return output;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
static void Mp4ToOgg(string fileName)
{
    DsReader dr = new DsReader(fileName);
    if (dr.HasAudio)
    {
        string waveFile = fileName + ".wav";
        WaveWriter ww = new WaveWriter(File.Create(waveFile),
            AudioCompressionManager.FormatBytes(dr.ReadFormat()));
        ww.WriteData(dr.ReadData());
        ww.Close();
        dr.Close();
        try
        {
            Sox.Convert(@"sox.exe", waveFile, waveFile + ".ogg", SoxAudioFileType.Ogg);
        }
        catch (SoxException ex)
        {
            throw;
        }

    }
}
```

from [How to converts a mp4 file to an ogg file](http://alvas.net/alvas.audio,tips.aspx#tip135)